# How to add and delete image in folder(desktop) through matlab gui?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How to add and delete specific image in folder(desktop) through matlab gui?

For example, I have a folder name FLOWER. Then when I open the gui, I can add new image and delete image that have in folder FLOWER. To design the gui i have no problem, but I'm stuck at the code to add and delete image.

Link for screenshot folder:

```
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGDkf.png][1]
```

Comment: Please, post the relevant part of the code. What do you mean with "add" the image? Do you want to save an image created with a plot?

Comment: what I mean is, I want to save/add an image that I choose from another folder and save it in FLOWER folder @il_raffa

Comment: If that is the case, codes in the Case3 might help. @Nur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create something, you could call the **imwrite** function(If I understand you correctly), and **delete** function could let you delete it.

Here are some demos:

```
%%Add and Delete image in folder
clc; clear;

%%Case1 : Save a figure
%Create
plot(1:10,1:10);
A=getframe(gcf);
%Write 
imwrite(A.cdata,'D:/FLOWER/img1.jpg');

%%Case2 : Create a image
%Create
B=zeros(100:100);
B(1:50,:)=1;
%Write
imwrite(mat2gray(B),'D:/FLOWER/img2.jpg');

%%Case3 : Load and save a image
%Load
C=imread('D:/FLOWER/flower.png');

%Do something with image
%imshow(C);
%C=C/2;

%Write
imwrite(C,'D:/FLOWER/img3.jpg');

%pause
disp('You could check your image now')
pause()

%delete image
delete('D:/FLOWER/img1.jpg')
delete('D:/FLOWER/img2.jpg')
delete('D:/FLOWER/img3.jpg')
```

*To run this demo, "flower.png" have to exist in the folder D:/FLOWER/ and then you will find a copy of it with the name of "img3.jpg"*

You could also try **copyfile('source','destination')** in case3.(*if you needn't show/change the image in the GUI*)

P.S. you may change the absolute path of your folder since I changed my desktop's path.

Comment: what do you mean by `plot(1:10,1:10)` is a sample image? Can you explain it @Hunter Jiang

Comment: because it will create a new figure(plotting GUI) and we could call the getframe function to get an image. If you need to save a real "image", a matrix of grayscale (or RGB) must be created or read. @Nur

Comment: yeah I already try your code and its very helpful. But why the added image turn to black white image? I have post the screenshot at description above(at Link for screenshot folder) @Hunter Jiang

Comment: Link of the screenshot from the error [https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGDkf.png] @Hunter Jiang

Comment: I updated my post with three different cases, the image in the case2 is black and white because I created a grayscale, and case3 might resolve your problem in the comment. @Nur